# Acumatica - PXDBScalar uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to populate this field with the value of a customer attribute.

```
  public class CustomerExt : PXCacheExtension<Customer>
  {
    #region OtherID
    [PXString]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Other ID")]
    [PXDBScalar(typeof(Search<CSAnswers.value,
        Where<CSAnswers.refNoteID, Equal<Current<Customer.noteID>>,
            And<CSAnswers.attributeID, Like<OtherIDAttr>>>>))]
    public virtual string UsrOtherID { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrOtherID : IBqlField { }
    #endregion 

    public class OtherIDAttr: Constant<string>
    {
        public OtherIDAttr() : base("OTHERID") { }
    }
}
```

It causes the above error when the field is added to a screen. If I remove the second condition from the Search<>, the field populates, so I'm sure its the comparison between the CSAnswers AttributeID and the constant string.

If someone could point me in the right direction, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you get this error due to the **Current** operator (`Equal<Current<Customer.noteID>>`) used within **PXDBScalarAttribute**.

Attempt to simply remove the **Current** operator led to a different error ***Invalid column name 'NoteID'.***, which can be resolved by the replacement of `Customer.noteID` with `PX.Objects.CR.BAccount.noteID`:

```
public class CustomerExt : PXCacheExtension<Customer>
{
    #region OtherID
    public abstract class usrOtherID : IBqlField { }

    [PXString]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Other ID")]
    [PXDBScalar(typeof(Search<CSAnswers.value,
        Where<CSAnswers.refNoteID, Equal<BAccount.noteID>,
            And<CSAnswers.attributeID, Like<OtherIDAttr>>>>))]
    public virtual string UsrOtherID { get; set; }
    #endregion

    public class OtherIDAttr : Constant<string>
    {
        public OtherIDAttr() : base("OTHERID") { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Worked like a charm